# Heap allocated with process end

Tags: memory-management, heap-memory

What happens to the allocated memory in heap at the process end?
Does the Operating system delete the heap memory allocate by that process or will it keep remaining?
Does the heap is global for all the processes or is there a heap for each process given by the OS?